# transition для текста и картинки

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как сделать плавное появление картинки, получается только текст. Заранее спасибо!

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: Monotype Corsiva;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #003399;
}

.menu .active {
  border-color: #003399;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background: #8B0000;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #FF4500;
  transition: 3s;
}

.main-menu>.active>a {
  color: white;
  background: #0088cc;
}

.main-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a:link img,
a:visited img {
  display: none;
}

a:hover img,
a:active img {
  display: block
}

a:link img {
  position: relative;
  left: 165px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#ulusoy">Чагатай Улусой <img src="ulusoy.jpg"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#duymaz">Альперен Дуймаз <img src="duymaz.jpg"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#aka">Кубилай Ака <img src="aka.jpg"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#andic">Фуркан Андыч <img src="andic.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: transition для текста получается, а для картинки куда его вставлять?

Answer (score 1):

**Что я сделал ?**

Я блок который появляется при `hover` отодвинул в право left: `calc(100% + 80px);` и так же выставил его вертикально по центру  `top: 50%; margin-top: -50%;` но что бы Родителем для скрытого элемента не был тот блок в котором он расположен я указал что родитель для него главный блок делается это так : `position:relative;` и при hover по очереди показываю установив `transition:0.5s;` при указании `opacity` который анимируется в отличие от `display`

> смотреть на весь экран

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.items{
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.img{
  position: absolute;
  left:calc(100% + 200px);
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-30%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:.5s;
  transform:scale(0);
}

.item{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:2em;
  zoom:0.6;
}
.item.blue{background:#0000cc;}
.item.darkred{background:#cc0000;}
.item.lightgreen{background:#00ff00;}

.item:hover .img{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
  transform:scale(2);
}

.item span{
  opacity:0.5;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.item:hover span{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item blue">
    <span>Block1</span>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/0000cc" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item darkred">
    <span>Block2</span>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/cc0000" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item lightgreen">
    <span>Block3</span>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/00ff00" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```